# Customize the sprint card in sprint view

Tags: azure-devops

Under sprints, in the backlog view, in your rightmost column all sprints and the backlog is visualised:

[image: Card view]

Under each sprint-card i get a field "Planned Effort" which i would like to change. I can't find that setting. I am both project and team administrator. Opening the settings in the upper rightmost corner I get this:

[image: settings]

How can I customise that card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Planned Effort" field exists by default when you select "Planing" in the side pane. It caculates a sum of all Story Points or Effort defined for backlog items assigned to the sprint. You cannot remove/change the field.

Please find the detail explainnation from official doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/assign-work-sprint?view=azure-devops#assign-work-from-your-backlog-to-a-sprint):
[image]

Comment: Can I add any more fields?

Comment: @Fija, no, you cannot add field on the Planing side pane default view.

Comment: @Fija, greetings! Could you please mark my reply if it make sense to you? so that it could help other guys who has same query. Let me know if you have any queries.